# Checking if field inside collection exists

Tags: mongodb, meteor

I'd like to check if a value inside a field of a collection doesn't exist.

I tried both ways. Once checking if it does exist, that worked out fine, as far as I can tell:

```
if (Characters.findOne({name:name})) {
      {throw new Meteor.Error('name exists');} };
```

It throws the error when you type in a name that already exists.

Now the other way around I tried

```
   if (  Characters.find( { name: { $not: { $eq: name } } } ) ) {
    {throw new Meteor.Error('name doesn't exist');}
 };
```

I expected that the error would only throw if a name was given that doesn't exist. I commented the first code out of course. But it also threw the error when a name that did exist was passed in.

I tried a lot of different operators but the result was always the same.

**Edit**

I tried the suggested way and it worked fine!

**Case: Name does exist:**

```
Meteor.methods({
  'characters.start'(name) {
   check(name, String);

if (Characters.findOne({name})) {
    throw new Meteor.Error('name exists');
} else {
 return Characters.insert({
      name,
      owner: Meteor.user().username,
      ownerId: Meteor.userId(),

    });
  }
},
```

**Case: Name doesn't exist:**

```
Meteor.methods({
  'characters.start'(name) {
   check(name, String);

if (Characters.findOne({name})) {
 return Characters.insert({
      name,
      owner: Meteor.user().username,
      ownerId: Meteor.userId(),
      });
} else {
  throw new Meteor.Error('name exists');
  }
},
```

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your query isn't going to work like you want it to. Names that don't match will always be returned.

The check for non-existence is simply the inverse of it existing:

```
if (Characters.findOne({name})) {
    throw new Meteor.Error('name exists');
} else {
    // It wasn't found, therefore it doesn't exist
    // - so you can create it now
}
```

I hope that makes sense :)